# Generating function of a combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $A_n$ be the set of all binary words of length $n$. Let $A(x,p,q)$ be the generating function of the number of words in $A_n$ when $x$ counts length 
, $p$ counts the number of $1$ (the number of appearance of $1$), $q$ counts the number of strings $00$.
Write a recursive structure for $\cup_{n} A_n$ for calculating the generating function and find it.
What is the average of the number of the string $00$ in $A_n$ .
Can you help me with this questions please, I'm puzzled with that topic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this problem, the structure of binary words makes it possible to derive the generating function without first finding the coefficients (and it's easier, too).  Note these facts about binary words:

- A word is either the empty word, a word ending in zero, or a word ending in one.
- A word ending in zero is either the word $0$, a word ending in zero followed by a zero, or a word ending in one followed by a zero.
- A word ending in one is an arbitrary word followed by a one.

Let's define $B(x,p,q)$ to be the generating function for words ending in a zero and $C(x,p,q)$ to be the generating function for words ending in a one.  Then the above observations translate into the following equations:
$$\begin{align}
A(x,p,q) &= 1 + B(x,p,q) + C(x,p,q) \\
B(x,p,q) &= x + qxB(x,p,q) + xC(x,p,q) \\
C(x,p,q) &= xpA(x,p,q)
\end{align}$$
Solve this system of three equations for $A(x,p,q)$ and you have the sought-after generating function.  You can then use that generating function to find the average number of $00$s in a word of length $n$ without needing to find the coefficients of the generating function.

Comment: Thanks that what i did , then when i find the statistic of 00's ... I have to find the cofficient of d/dq A(x,0,1) / A(x,0,1)??  @awkward

Comment: @Almaa Yes, that's correct.  You might as well start by setting $p=1$ to simplify $A$. Then you will need to find the partial of $A$ with respect to $q$, then set $q=1$.  This will give you a GF, and you will need to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in that GF.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started ...

Let $X_{n,p,q}$ denote the number of binary words with $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $00$'s that end with $00$.

Let $Y_{n,p,q}$ denote the number of binary words with $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $00$'s that end with $10$.

Let $Z_{n,p,q}$ denote the number of binary words with $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $00$'s that end with $1$.

Your $A_{n,p,q}$if given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{n,p,q}= X_{n,p,q} + Y_{n,p,q} +Z_{n,p,q}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$X,Y,Z$ satisfy the following recurrence relations
\begin{eqnarray*}
&X_{n+1,p,q+1} &=&  X_{n,p,q} + Y_{n,p,q} \\
&Y_{n+1,p,q}&=& &Z_{n,p,q}  \\
&Z_{n+1,p+1,q}&=& X_{n,p,q} + Y_{n,p,q}+ & Z_{n,p,q}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

You now need to do some algebra to get a recurrence relation that only involves $A$. ... Good luck ... $ \ddot \smile$